# One view called by two different controllers (A form contained with in a view calls another controller)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

Dear Friends: It seems like more of a Conceptual problem than a programming problem. Am new to MVC and have problems in understanding what can call what. THE FLOW OF PROGRAM CONTROL.

The Problem: Controller A --Calls-->Model A--calls-->View A. Now once the View A is loaded it also contains a form for inserting comment with a sumbitt button.

Once the comments are inserted (and submitted) it calls Controller B--calls-->Mocel B. which insert data into comments table -- further it has NO View to call.

QUESTION 1: how to call the Controller A from Model B (since model B does not have a view). it is possible to load ViewA from ModelB but that will require to re-write the code that exists in Controller a already. FURTHER more i want the comment form to be inserted into many pages so will i have to reload all those pages (Views) manually.

Question2: it is possible to make comments form (Controller B and Model B) part of Controller A and Model A BUT then comment form will cease to be a re-usable module and will need to be inserted into every page that i like it to be used in.

Question3: Is there some conceptual error i an making. it is the way MCV works?

Summary:: There is a form managed by Controller B and Modal B (it has no view and it displayed as part of a page managed by Controller A, Model A and View A) Model Bafter doing its job it needs to call Controller A (so that it can refresh the page) HOW?
THANKS TO YOU BRAVE SOULS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Structures from model layer (yes, in proper MVC-inspired architecture the model is not a class) should never have any knowledge about the rest of application. Model should not call the controller. **Never!**. I think the core of your problem is, that, while you are trying to understand MVC, you are using CodeIgniter an blueprint for what MVC pattern should look like. But the CodeIgniter's MVC implementation is completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think your strategy is a little off starting with

> Controller A --Calls-->Model A--calls-->View A

Your models really shouldn't be calling your view.  The controller is usually in charge of this.  Requests are made to the controller and the controller gets all the data from the model then formats/templates it using a view and outputs it to a user.  Controllers should be at the center of every request.

> QUESTION 1 how to call the Controller A from Model B?

Model B really shouldn't be calling a controller.  MVC really isn't desinger for this. If you need data from model B get it from the controller.  If you need functionality that exists in controller A refactor it into a utilty function that can be used anywhere in your app.

> Question2: it is possible to make comments form (Controller B and
>   Model B) part of Controller A?

Yes once again this comes from a good app design.  I'd imagine that one of your models is able to retrieve comments.  Perhaps per user perhaps per time frame.  From controller A you can call that model function.  By loading the model `$this->load->model('Post')`
and retireving your posts `$this->Post->most_recent_posts()`.

> Question3: Is there some conceptual error i an making. it is the way
>   MCV works?

Yes the functions of your site are too tightly bound to their controllers and models.  They hve to be more loose/general so functionality can be used in any controller.

I'd like to answer you last/main point but it would really really help to see some code.

Comment: Oh Bloody Hell... It was soooo simple..

just where my model finished working.... i can
            redirect('/controllerA/method of controller A','refresh');
this will simply refresh the page . it is refered to **internal redirect ** in some forums.

also remember that redirect() is function of URI helper class so either have it autoloaded or manually load it.


Thanks a lot fiends Specially dm03514

Comment: MR dm03514 Such a better answer Thanks a lot..Point 1:: thats is exactly what i have done the model--reports back to --controller and then --controller calls---view (but i failed to write it so) Point2:: The model B after completion of its calculations can just hand over the control to Controller A by redirecting() as i have explained below... thanks a lot